# How to identify if a given username belongs to Gmail or G Suite account?

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

Currently, I am facing a scenario, where I should differentiate whether a given user belongs to a Gmail account or a G Suite account.

I have the email id of the user. As of now, the only visible difference is that the email address has a different domain name for a G Suite account. For an normal Gmail account the domain name is "gmail.com".

I don't feel safe to rely on this. What is the recommended way to identify the account type of an user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is safe to rely on, and many users have already used this technique successfully.
Emails addresses contain only one "@" sign, so in order to verify this you could use a simple function such as:

```js
function isGSuite(email) {
  return email.split("@")[1] != 'gmail.com';
}
```

In fact, there is no API or any other method you can use to check whether the account is actually a GSuite account. Given an e-mail address that is not `gmail`, there is no public way of determining whether it is part of a GSuite domain, since that could present security and privacy issues.

Comment: Thanks, we also noticed that Google requires a domain name to sign up for G Suite. https://support.google.com/a/answer/53926?hl=en